# Combinatorial problem on 2 competing players and a fair pair of die. Need help in understanding the given solution

Tags: combinatorics

*Alice and Bob are playing the following game. They roll a pair of fair die. If the outcome is 6, Alice wins. If the outcome is a 3 or 5, Bob wins. Otherwise they say the roll was indecisive and keep rolling until either a 6 (Alice wins) or, an outcome of 3 or 5 is rolled (Bob wins). What is the probability that Alice eventually wins?*

**Given solution:**

Let A = {current roll is a 6}, B = {current roll is a 3 or 5} and C = {current roll is not a 3, 5 or 6}.

Then P(A) = 5/36, P(B) = 6/36 and P(C) = 25/36.

Let E = {Alice eventually wins}.

$P(E) = P(E|A)P(A) + P(E|B)P(B) + P(E|C)P(C)$
$ = 1 * \frac{5}{36} + 0 * \frac{6}{36} * P(E) \frac{25}{36} = \frac{5}{11}$

---

I did not understand what does P(E) mean in the place of P(E|C), well, if we are given C then P(E) must be 0, right? Moreover, not sure what P(E) really means inside the computation of P(E)...

Comment: You double-counted $(3,3)$.

Comment: To answer your question directly, $P(E|C)$ is the probability that Alice *eventually* wins, given that the current roll is not 3, 5, or 6. It doesn’t represent the probability that Alice wins *on the current roll* if the current roll is not 3, 5, or 6. The latter probability is 0, and perhaps you thought that’s what $P(E|C)$ meant. It’s an easy mistake to make, since the distinction between winning on the current roll and eventually winning isn’t important when calculating the previous conditional probabilities $P(E|A)$ and $P(E|B)$, where the game happens to end with the current roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\frac{5}{36}$ comes from $P(A)$, we can throw 6 by $(1,5), (2,4), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1)$ so there are 5 ways out of 36 (we are throwing with two dice).

The probability of $3$ is $\frac{2}{36}$ from the possibilities $(1,2), (2,1)$. And for 5 we have 4 options: $(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)$, so in total $\frac{6}{36} = P(B)$.

$P(C) = 1 - P(A) - P(B)$ as the options are all mutually exclusive and cover all options.

The options are enumerated as (value of die 1, value of die 2) above. There is only one way to have $(3,3)$ so we count it once.. (if you see 4 and 2, there are two ways this could happen: $(4,2)$ and $(2,4)$; image that the dice are different colours so they can be distinguished, so they would look different as well. $(3,3)$ can only happen one way.

The final part when we replace $P(E | C)$ by $P(E)$ is the following reasoning: after one throw, we either have a winner (the first two options) are the throw was inconclusive. After the inconclusive throw (so in the case that $C$ occurs) the chances are still the same as they were before we first threw the dice; we have a "reset". So the chance that Alice wins after an inconclusive throw ($P(E|C)$) is the same as her original chances $P(E)$.

Comment: Cool, thanks, the way to imagine die in different colors helped. Though I am still confused about computation part.. and P(E) being replacement for P(E|C)... and how we can compute P(E) having P(E) inside computation